# Why does the Stack Overflow app come with a history function?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-app

In the Stack Overflow app, there is an option where we can see our browsing history.

But on the desktop Stack Overflow site, we can only see all actions, which does not contain browsing history.

So why does the app come with history function? (And will the desktop site also get an equivalent function? I know I shouldn't ask 2 questions at once.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature doesn't need to be on the site because web browsers already take care of tracking your browsing history.

But the app isn't a browser and so you wouldn't have that history without it saving it for you.

Comment: But another thing: this way the mobile only have mobile history, and PC only have PC history...

Comment: I often browse SO on my PC, then sometimes I leave the PC and used my phone. I cant see what I search previously

Comment: Firefox and Chrome both offer sync options for keeping history across multiple machines / devices, @SteveFest - I highly recommend it for exactly the reason you stated.

Comment: @Shog9 Does the Stack Overflow app writes history into chrome? I used the SO app

Comment: I have the mutli device history set up already. But the SO app doesn't interact with Chrome?

Comment: Yeah, that's the downside of using apps. Well, one of 'em.

Comment: You know... Phone doesn't support HTML as well as a PC.. browsing using phone Chrome hurts :(

Comment: @SteveFest are you using the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Nah.. I use the Stack Overflow app for SO, and the Stack Exchange app for the other sites

Comment: Give a try to the mobile version of the website, it's quite good !